# how to estimate a multiple indefinite integral with constant integrand?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

Let $\rho_i,\eta_i\in[a,b]$. How to prove the following inequality?
\begin{equation*}
\left|\int_{\eta_{k+1}}^{\rho_{k+1}}d\rho_k\int_{\eta_{k}}^{\rho_{k}}d\rho_{k-1}\cdots\int_{\eta_{2}}^{\rho_2}d\rho_1\right|\leq \frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}.
\end{equation*}
I have spent much time, but nothing come out. I think it could be probably proven by Induction, but I didn't get a right way.

Comment: actually, when integrating the integrals one by one, the expression becomes more and more complicated, which is very difficult to estimate.

Comment: Set $a$ to $0$, without the loss of generality, then set all $\eta$ to $0$

Comment: the case that all $\eta=0$ does not represent an upper-bound case. because some $\rho_i$ may be very close to $\eta_i$

Comment: no, $\rho_{k+1}$ is a constant. It seems that you miss understand. Because some $\rho_i$ is larger than $\eta_i$ while some $\rho_i$ is less than $\eta_i$. Setting all $\eta_i$ to zero does not solve everything. Some $\eta_i$ should be set to be $b$.

Comment: Sorry, but it's you who misunderstands...

Comment: All I want to do is to prove the inequality strictly without talking about intuition. If you think your idea is right, could you write it down?

Comment: It is strictly true that taking $a=0$ leads to equivalent problem, meanwhile setting all $\eta=0$, and $\rho_{k+1}=b$ gives us the equality case by direct integration. If you don't want to do that, that's alright.

Comment: Yes, when setting $\eta=0$ and $\rho_{k+1}$, then the right hand side equal to the left hand side. But then? I still don't know why it is the upper bound. One may argue that there may exists other setting which is larger than $\frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}$.  If one can further prove that the value of right hand side is symmetric with respect to distribution of $\eta_i$, then combining this symmetry with your idea solves the proof. But the symmetry may be even more difficult to prove than the original problem.

Comment: Your function is positive everywhere. There can't be a choice of parameters leading to larger value. It could be shown by geometric argument, or interval arithmetic... Note that with the choice we made all the variables are restricted to $[0,b]$.

Comment: Thanks. I think your proof works.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need an absolutely rigorous proof, you could post your version as an answer to this question, and ask other users to check it.